# https://<website> not working with Godaddy

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-eks, godaddy-api

So I have a kubernetes cluster managed by AWS. I have a domain + dns managed by GoDaddy. Everything works except for `https://<domain>`

When I hit this the url that's opened is `http://<domain>.com`.

I have forwarding set up to `https://www.<domain>.com`.

Why does this happen?

Comment: How come you want to open "https://<domain>" instead of  "https://<domain>.com"? Please update your question

Comment: A single label domain is not valid on the internet... you domain is <name>.<tld> with the bit after the '.' there is no way round this unless its an internal private network.